# Access form edit doesn't save when closing with acSaveYes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I can't get Access to save a form I have edited using VBA to hide (or unhide) a column.  The basic code is below.  I open the form (in Datasheet mode because I am changing the ColumnHidden property), make the change, and close and save, but it doesn't save the change.  Experimenting, I changed acSaveYes to acSavePrompt, and it doesn't even prompt me to save.  Does this have anything to do with being in datasheet mode?  Never had this problem making similar edits in design mode.  If so, how do I make and save such a change.  Thanks for any ideas!

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acFormDS
Forms![Form1].MyColumn.ColumnHidden = True
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form1", acSaveYes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes you make using VBA are seen as temporary by Access, and not saved, even if you explicitly save your object. This behavior is intended (and very useful, as it allows you to hide things on the fly based on whatever you want without you having to worry about reverting changes after the user is done with the form). An exception to this is when the user first lets VBA make changes, then switches to layout view and makes additional changes, and then saves the object. In that case the changes made by VBA are saved.

As far as I know, you cannot change this. Obviously, you can make the change manually and then save it, or check if the column should be visible or not once you open the form based on something you set somewhere.